# Running time of algorithm

Tags: algorithm, big-o

Hi this is a question from an exam review. I have to find the running time(in Big-O) of the following code fragment.

```
sum = 0; 
for( i = 0; i < n; i++ ) 
 for( j = 0; j < i * i; j++ ) 
  for ( k = 0; k < j; k++ ) 
    ++sum;
```

I think that it is O(n^4). The innermost loop executes to n, the second executes to n^2, and the outermost executes n times. Thank you all for your help

Comment: Look at the innermost loop more carefully.

Comment: innerloop runs to n^2 also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not O(4).

A better way to see this is to count how many times the loop executes(in fact, that is what the code is doing).

sum(sum(sum(1, k=0..j), j=0..i*i), i=0..n)

= sum(sum(j,j=0..i*i),i=0..n) = sum(i*i*(i*i+1)/2,i=0..n)
which is on the order of sum(i^4, i=0..n) which is on the order of n^5.

Essentially because the middle loop is i*i and is being executed for each of the inner most loop it needs to be counted an extra time.

In C++

http://codepad.org/nKJ9IUnt

```
1 0
2 0
3 6
4 42
5 162
6 462
7 1092
8 2268
9 4284
10 7524
11 12474
12 19734
13 30030
14 44226
15 63336
16 88536
17 121176
18 162792
19 215118
```

You can use this table and compute the finite differences(taking derivatives) until the result is a constant or 0. You'll find that it takes 5 derivatives to have a constant list. This means that it the list is on the order of n^5.

e.g., If we had a list where each difference between two elements were a constant then the list could be represented by a linear function. If the difference of the difference was constant then it would be a quadradic, etc.  (it doesn't matter about the lower order terms because they get translated by the derivative/difference)

Answer (score 1):

Formally, using Sigma Notation would help to deduce the order of growth with sharp precision.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can think simply:

```
In the first loop: i = n
second loop: j = i*i => j = n^2
third loop: k = j => k = n^2
So, the bigO = n * n^2 * n^2 = n^5
```